# Current filename from the library function in Python

Tags: python, filenames

Function f in lib.py returns os.path.basename.

When I call f() from 1.py it returns me 'lib.py'. 
How can I modify f() so that it will return me '1.py'?

Comment: You need to supply ut with the code you're using. `f()` is not a built in function.

Comment: please add code snippet.

Comment: Are you asking how to find out which function has called `f` and output the file where that function is defined? If yes, that doesn't sound like a good idea - perhaps you could explain in more detail what you're trying to do. If no, well, what _are_ you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you need `sys.argv[0]` — a CLI argument #0 is the script being executed.

This also does not depend if it is called as `python 1.py` or `./1.py`. For both cases, `sys.executable` can be used by find the python binary file. The script will always be argument #0.

It will be an empty string when called from an interactive mode, though. Because there is no script being executed.